Issue with creating a custom layer in Tensorflow
When I try to create a simple implementation of a custom layer in Tensorflow I get the error:
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py:178 in __getattr__
    if item in ("_tfll_mode", "_tfll_initialized", "_tfll_name"):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

This is my code:
import tensorflow as tf

class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
            "kernel",
            shape=[int(input_shape[-1]), self.num_outputs],
            initializer='random_normal',  # Initialize with random values
            trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)


input_dim = 4  # Number of input features
output_dim = 2  # Match the target data output dimension
layer = MyDenseLayer(output_dim)

# Create a simple model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)  # Ensure the final output matches the target
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Create random input data
x = tf.random.normal((5, input_dim))  # Batch size of 5
y = tf.random.normal((5, 2))  # Random target data for training

# Train the model
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10)

Besides compiling the model, most of the code comes from tensorflow documentation. I am using Tensorflow 2.17.0.

In Staging Ground I commented that you have to still add the beginning of the traceback, you still need to do that, else we don't know how the code relates to the error.

I posted the entire console output, but I don't see last most recent traceback in that output.

You can redirect console output to a file (python something.py 2>&1 > log.txt) to get the full log in a single file, not limited by your current terminal.

Thank you. For some reason, just running the .py  in my terminal even without redirecting console output shows the traceback as opposed to Spyder.
